# Query to select all oldest books of all shops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Given a simple Book/Shop association as follows, and assuming Book has a `published_on` Date.

```
class Shop
  has_many :books
end

class Book
  belongs_to: shop
end
```

How would you build a PostgreSQL query that returns all books that have the oldest published for the shop they belong to.

So if you have this dataset (date format is YYYY-MM-DD):

- Shop A:

  - Book A1 - published_on: 2019-01-01
  - Book A2 - published_on: 2019-02-01
  - Book A3 - published_on: 2019-03-01
- Shop B:

  - Book B1 - published_on: 2019-04-01
  - Book B2 - published_on: 2019-04-01
  - Book B3 - published_on: 2019-05-01
- Shop C:

  - Book C1 - published_on: 2019-02-01
  - Book C1 - published_on: 2019-06-01

It should return:

- Book A1 - published_on: 2019-01-01
- Book B1 - published_on: 2019-04-01
- Book B2 - published_on: 2019-04-01
- Book C1 - published_on: 2019-02-01

I know how to get all `published_on` dates by Shop:

```
Book.select('shop_id, min(published_on) as min_pub').group(:shop_id)
```

But I'm not sure where to go next, or if that's useful even.

Comment: Do you need an actual SQL query or are you trying to do this using Active Record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use the query you have so far as a subquery to get the list of books:

```
SELECT books.*
FROM books
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT shop_id, min(published_on) as min_pub
  FROM "books"
  GROUP BY shop_id
) AS jt ON jt.min_pub = books.published_on
        AND jt.shop_id = books.shop_id
```

I'm not sure if Active Record can help to build this subquery... The only thing I can imagine is something like:

```
subquery = Book.select('shop_id, min(published_on) as min_pub').group(:shop_id).to_sql
Book.joins(
  "INNER JOIN (#{subquery}) AS jt ON jt.min_pub = books.published_on AND jt.shop_id = books.shop_id"
)
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I was a bit rusty on my subqueries :)

Answer (score 0):

That should be the sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM books
JOIN shop on books.shop_id = shops.id
ORDER BY books.published_on
GROUP BY shop
```

translated to Active Record it could look like this:
`Books.joins(:shops).order(:published_on).group(shop.id)`

I am not exactly sure about the grouping part :) Let me know what the result is and we can figure it out togehter